Limit definition of mixed partial derivative
Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable w.r.t $x,y$. Is it true that:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x \partial y} f(x,y) = \lim_{\Delta x \to 0, \Delta y \to 0} \frac{f(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y) - f(x,y)}{\Delta x \Delta y}?
\end{equation}
In other words, given $\epsilon>0$ I can find $\delta$ such that when $(\Delta x, \Delta y)$ is $\delta$-close (w.r.t. Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}^2$) to $(0,0)$, then $\frac{f(x + \Delta x, y + \Delta y) - f(x,y)}{\Delta x \Delta y}$ is $\epsilon$-close (w.r.t. Euclidean metric in $\mathbb{R}$) to $\frac{\partial}{\partial x \partial y} f(x,y)$.
(I apologize if this is exactly the definition of the mixed partial. I cannot find this definition anywhere I look, they all seem to be with respect to one of the variables which gave me the impression that differentiation needs to be done one variable at a time.)

A mixed partial derivative is a second order derivative, so it kinda needs to happen one at a time. Though this definition is equivalent (since you are taking two limits)

Normally have $\partial^2/\partial x, \partial y$

No, this is not the same. You have to write it explicitly as a limit of a limit. Your expression is symmetric in $\Delta x$ and $\Delta y$, but there are plenty of functions for which $\partial^2 f/\partial x\partial y$ is not equal to $\partial^2 f/\partial y\partial x$.

Assume $f$ is $C^2$ at $(x,y)$ and consider the Taylor expansion at $(x,y)$. Then (evaluating all derivatives at the point $(x,y)$), we have
\begin{align*}
f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y) &= f(x,y) + \\  &\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Delta x+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Delta y + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(\Delta x)^2+2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x\partial y}\Delta x\Delta y + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(\Delta y)^2 + \varepsilon,
\end{align*}
where $\varepsilon$ goes to $0$ faster than $(\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2$. Now plug this into your limit and you have all sorts of trouble unless all those other partial derivatives vanish.
Indeed, just try a simple polynomial like $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$. You have
$$\frac{f(x+\Delta x,y+\Delta y)-f(x,y)}{\Delta x\Delta y} = \frac{2x\Delta x+(\Delta x)^2 + 2y\Delta y + (\Delta y)^2}{\Delta x\Delta y}.$$
This limit horribly does not exist. It is very far from the mixed partial derivative, which is of course $0$.

Does this become true if we tighten restrictions on f? What if f (F) is a joint CDF of two random variables? I saw this "fact" used in a derivation regarding order statistics so I'm just wondering where it came from.

I am highly suspicious that it can hold in any general situation whatsoever. Even if you rig it to get around my counterexample, by doing $f(x,y)=xy$, notice that the first derivative terms still blow up. Perhaps the statistics derivation is just wrong.

Apologies as this may be more a comment than an answer, but perhaps the expression you want is closer to this:
$$
\frac{f(x+\Delta_x, y+\Delta_y)-f(x+\Delta_x,y)-f(x,y+\Delta_y) + f(x,y)}{\Delta_x\Delta_y}
$$
For any non-zero $s_1,s_2\in \mathbb R$ if we define $\Delta_{1,s_1}(f)(x) = \frac{f(x+s_1,y)-f(x,y)}{s_1}$ and $\Delta_{2,s_2}(f)(x) = \frac{f(x,y+s_2)-f(x,y)}{s_2}$. Then $\Delta_{1,s}$ and $\Delta_{2,t}$ are linear operators, and clearly $\partial_i\Delta_{j,s_j} = \Delta_{j,s_j}\circ \partial_i$ for $i,j \in \{1,2\}$, and similarly $\Delta_{1,s_1}\Delta_{2,s_2} = \Delta_{2,s_2}\Delta_{1,s_1}$
Now $\partial_1f(x) = \lim_{s_1\to 0} \Delta_{1,s_1}(f)(x)$ and similarly $\partial_2 f(x) = \lim_{s_2\to 0} \Delta_{2,s_2}(f)(x)$, so that
$$
\begin{split}
\partial_1\partial_2 f(x) &= \lim_{s_1\to 0} \Delta_{1,s_1}\partial_2(f)(x)\\
&= \lim_{s_1 \to 0} \partial_2\Delta_{1,s_1}(f)(x)\\
&= \lim_{s_1 \to 0} \lim_{s_2\to 0}\Delta_{2,s_2}\Delta_{1,s_1}(f)\\
&= \lim_{s_1\to 0}\lim_{s_2\to 0} \left(\frac{f(x+s_1,y+s_2)-f(x+s_1,y)-f(x,y+s_2) + f(x,y)}{s_1s_2}\right)
\end{split}
$$
Essentially, the above along with the fact that the difference operators $\Delta_{1}$ and $\Delta_{2}$ commute are the ingredients needed in the proof that the (total) second derivative is a symmetric bilinear form (when it exists).
